# Optimize an if/else statement code with lambda in C# ? Try to use only one Frame instead of parentIFrame and insurancedata

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following lines of code which I want to shorten using a lambda statement or anything more elegant.

```
 HtmlControl parentIFrame = null;
 HtmlControl insurancedata = null;

if (!Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("getactivityid"))
{
    parentIFrame = new HtmlControl(Resource.ProjectBrowserWindow);
       if (Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink"))
           parentIFrame.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "bike-insurance");
       else
           parentIFrame.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "section_wise_container");
}

if (Resource.ControlGenricName.ToLower().Contains("finalsubmitbutton"))
{
    insurancedata = new HtmlControl(parentIFrame);                    
    insurancedata.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, 
    "ResultButton");
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder, optimization and readability are not the same. When I read the title to your question I thought you wanted to make your code run faster, but after reading your explanation I realize you want to make it more elegant and short.

Comment: Whatever you do, this will never look elegant.... adding a lambda would only make it harder to understand

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Start with what you know. You can remove some duplication by doing `var propName; if(...) { propName = "bike-insurance" } else { propName = "section_wise_container" }`, and then adding `propName` to the `SearchProperties` collection. Having said that, this question might be a better fit for the [Code Review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Check what their guidelines are before posting there, though.

Comment: BTW, after you just reduce duplication as much as possible, it's often much easier to see where to add lambdas, or some other high-level changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere to use a lambda in this code.

You can shorten the code by

1. Declaring variables when you use them instead of before
2. Using object initializer and collection initializer syntax to add the property
3. Choosing the property value to set rather than choosing a logic branch to set it

Example:

```
if (!Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("getactivityid"))
{
    var parentIFrame = new HtmlControl(Resource.ProjectBrowserWindow)
    {
        SearchProperties =
        {
            HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, 
            (Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink")) ? "bike-insurance" : "section_wise_container" 
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: One observation: he cannot declare parentIFrame inside the if statement because he uses it later on, on the second if. The other variable (insurancedata), however, he can declare when used.

Comment: How can I use the second part of the code:

if (Resource.ControlGenricName.ToLower().Contains("finalsubmitbutton"))
{
    insurancedata = new HtmlControl(parentIFrame);                    
    insurancedata.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, 
    "ResultButton");
}


I need to use only one Iframe variable for both code.
How can I optimize to two use only one HtmlControl Frame instead of two.

Comment: Which means that the second part of the code will operate on a `null` variable if the first `if` block doesn't fire. No good. Put the second `if` inside the first `if` block. Or refactor.

Comment: Second part of the code use ParentIframe as a Browser.
In this way I get the child I frame in insurancedata.
and I also want to replace the insurancedata with ParentIframe so that I can use only one HtmlControl for both code.

Comment: I am getting the below mention error after using the code:
{"The PropertyExpressionCollection.Add method can take only in name-value pairs.\r\nParameter name: nameValuePairs"}

Answer (score 0):

No matter how much I look, it really doesn't seem appropriate to me to use lambda here. Try and encapsulate your code into functions, this way you will hide the ugly part.

Something like:

```
HtmlControl parentIFrame = GetParentIFrame();
HtmlControl insurancedata = GetInsuranceData(parentIFrame);
```

And then:

```
HtmlControl GetParentIFrame()
{
    HtmlControl parentIFrame = null;
    if (!Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("getactivityid"))
    {
        parentIFrame = new HtmlControl(Resource.ProjectBrowserWindow);
        if (Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink"))
           parentIFrame.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "bike-insurance");
        else
           parentIFrame.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "section_wise_container");
        return parentIFrame;
   }
   return parentIFrame;
}

HtmlControl GetInsuranceData(HtmlControl parentIFrame)
{
    HtmlControl insurancedata = null;
    if (Resource.ControlGenricName.ToLower().Contains("finalsubmitbutton"))
    {
        HtmlControl insurancedata = new HtmlControl(parentIFrame);                    
        insurancedata.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, 
        "ResultButton");
    }
    return insurancedata;
}
```

Comment: This one is not useful.

Comment: Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method, you can simplify the code by using a Fluent philosophy:

```
public static class HtmlControlExt {
    public static HtmlControl AddIdSearch(this HtmlControl ctrl, string name) {
        ctrl.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, name);
        return ctrl;
    }
}
```

Now your code would be:

```
if (!Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("getactivityid"))
{
    parentIFrame = new HtmlControl(Resource.ProjectBrowserWindow)
                        .AddIdSearch(Resource.ControlType.ToLower().Equals("hyperlink") ? "bike-insurance" : "section_wise_container");
}

if (Resource.ControlGenericName.ToLower().Contains("finalsubmitbutton"))
{
    insurancedata = new HtmlControl(parentIFrame)
                        .AddIdSearch("ResultButton");
}
```

NOTE: I would eliminate braces from single statement `if` and compare strings with `==`, so the code would be even shorter:

```
if (!Resource.ControlType.ToLower() == "getactivityid")
    parentIFrame = new HtmlControl(Resource.ProjectBrowserWindow)
                        .AddIdSearch(Resource.ControlType.ToLower() == "hyperlink" ? "bike-insurance" : "section_wise_container");

if (Resource.ControlGenericName.ToLower().Contains("finalsubmitbutton"))
    insurancedata = new HtmlControl(parentIFrame)
                        .AddIdSearch("ResultButton");
```

Comment: Fluent is an interesting direction, but this is a poor example. This code does not reveal the underlying structure or algorithm of the code very well.

Comment: @jpaugh Not sure what you mean... seems very clear to me! Obviously, you could make the extension method `void` and just use it after the assignment.

Comment: Of course it does; you wrote it. :-) I mean, that for a newcomer to the code, the OP's original code (hidden away in a function somewhere, in order to catch both the high-level and low-level details clearly) is actually easier to understand. You've made it denser, but (IMO) have sacrificed clarity, somewhat. Note, that I haven't read your code thoroughly, so take this with a grain of salt; but that is also part of the point I'm trying to make: the "ideal" is that I wouldn't have to.